# Get upload status in webpy

Tags: python, progress-bar, web.py

I'm making an uploader for my project, and I try to avoid any flash-based solutions (I dont like flash much and target for mobile platforms support).
The whole process seems rather simple: I have a form, nice jQuery progress bar, I can make ajax requests with timeout from a script to update progressbar status...
If I do it according to Webpy cookbook, the only thing I don't get is how to recieve any info from server: how many bytes/chunks/whatever were already written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create ajax uploader using FormData for the modern browsers.

```
$.fn.uploader = function( options ) {
    var defaults = {},
        opts = $.extend( defaults, options ),
        that = $( this ),
        url = that.data( "upload_url" ),
        is_uploading = false;

    function upload( files ) {

        $.get( "/file/blank.html" );

        if ( FormData === undefined ) {
            alert( "Your browser does not support standard HTML5 Drag and Drop" );
            return;
        }        

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
            new_element = $( "<li><p>Loading</p><span></span></li>" )
                .appendTo( that ),
            xhr_upload = xhr.upload,
            form = new FormData();

        xhr_upload.addEventListener( "progress", function( e ) {
            if( e.lengthComputable ) {
                var p = Math.round( e.loaded * 100 / e.total );
                new_element.children( "span" ).text( e.loaded == e.total ? "Processing..." : p + "%" );
            }
        }, false);
        xhr_upload.addEventListener( "load", function( e ){}, false);
        xhr_upload.addEventListener( "error", function( error ) { alert( "error: " + error ); }, false);

        xhr.open( "POST", url, true );
        xhr.setRequestHeader( "X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest" );

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function ( e ) {
            if ( xhr.readyState == 4 ) {
                is_uploading = false;
                if( xhr.status == 200 ) {
                    var data = $.parseJSON( e.target.responseText );
                    if ( data.status == 0 ) {
                        new_element
                            .fadeOut(function (){ $( this ).remove(); })
                            .children( "span" ).text( "Upload error!" );
                    } else {
                        that.html( data.html );
                    }
                } else {
                    new_element
                        .fadeOut(function (){ $( this ).remove(); })
                        .children( "span" ).text( "Upload error!" );
                }
            }
        };
        $.each( files, function() {
            form.append( "files", this );
        });
        is_uploading = true;
        xhr.send( form );
    }

    that.bind({
        "dragover": function( e ) {
            var dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
            if( !dt || is_uploading ) { return; };
            if( $.browser.webkit ) { dt.dropEffect = "copy"; };
            $( this ).addClass( "active" );
            return false;
        },
        "dragleave": function( e ) {
            $( this ).removeClass( "active" );
        },
        "dragenter": function( e ){ return false; },
        "drop": function( e ){
            var dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
            $( this ).removeClass( "active" );
            if( !dt || !dt.files || is_uploading ) { return; };
            upload( dt.files );
            return false;
        }
    });

    $( document ).bind({
        'dragenter': function( e ) { return false; },
        'dragleave': function( e ) { return false; },
        'dragover': function( e ) {
            var dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
            if ( !dt ) { return; }
            dt.dropEffect = "none";
            return false;
        }
    });

};
```

On the server side I process it like this:

```
def POST(self):
    i = web.webapi.rawinput()
    try:
        files = i.files
        if not isinstance(files, list):
            files = [files]
        for f in files:
            if f.filename:
                filetype, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(f.filename)
                # do smth with f.file
    except KeyError:
        pass
    if web.ctx.env.get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest':
        web.header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        return json.dumps(dict(status=1, html=unicode(render_partial.files(uploaded_files))))
    else:
        raise web.seeother(web.ctx.env.get("HTTP_REFERER", "/"))
```

Otherwise you may look into [nginx upload progress](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUploadProgressModule) module or apache2 upload progress module, [uWSGI](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Doc#upload-progress) has got this feature too.

Comment: can you give some more explanation? Especially on JS part. As I understood, I should apply `uploader()` function to div and use it as a 'upload field', but what `$.get( "/file/blank.html" );` line is for? Maybe you have use case to examine?

Comment: It is taken from http://www.smilingsouls.net/Blog/20110413023355.html?hSearchCursor=1/2/1 Just read the comment there at the line 078. It fixes some Safari bug. As for upload url, in my code it should be in data-upload_url attribute of the div.

Comment: and whats reference to `render_partial`?

Comment: and how do you get `uploaded_files` value?

Comment: I have noticed, that if you upload several files at once, it defines mimetypes of each file right, but replaces name and contents of each file with name and contents of the first file in a row (as it seems through simple `print filetype` and `print i.files`)

Comment: `render_partial` is an instance of web.py templator renderer without base layout. `uploaded_files` is a list of uploaded files (I insert them into db when I `#do smth with the file` and then select all uploads. Then `files.html` template renders list of all uploaded files and javascript sets the contents of the uploader div.

Comment: it should put on a div !? or file input ?